# Shorten feed_item links on the fly

Tags: feeds

I am using ***feeds*** module. The site structure creates a new **feed_item** for each item in the parsed rss

I want that upon the arrival of each ***feed_item***, the link be shortened. I read about few related modules, but all require manual intervention.

I am ready to insert some api function into the feeds module, but where to insert it exactly, that is out of my knowledge. Please help.

Currently using ***Shurly***

Answer (score 0):

Done using '[Shurly](https://www.drupal.org/project/shurly)' and '[feeds_tamper_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper_php)' module.

After enabling both the modules, add

> Execute PHP Code

plugin to

> Feed Importer's field_url

.

Execute the following code:

```
$shortUrl = shurly_shorten($field);
return $shortUrl['shortUrl'];
```